# How to implode JavaScript into PHP's return function?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP function:

```
function output_errors($errors) {
    return '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
}
```

But instead of `<ul>` and `<li>`s I wish to use jQuery to show errors:

```
$(function() {
    $.pnotify({
        title: 'Update Successful!',
        text: '<p>Error text here!</p>',
    });
});
```

I tried a lot of combinations but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What specifically doesnt work ? Just Simply implode with a comma :

```
            function output_errors($errors) {
                $error = implode(', ', $errors);
                echo <<< xyz
<script>
                $(function() {
                $.pnotify({
                  title: 'Update Successful!',
                  text: '$error',
                 });
                });
</script>
xyz;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But still one problem is remaining.. if there is more than 1 error output it doesn't show it in js :(

Comment: then what happens ? what is the output ?

Comment: I mean that if I have 1 error like : "Password does not match this account"  it works great.. but if I have 2 errors  like A and B  it doesn't show js box but instead html code

Answer (score 0):

The counterpart of `implode` is `join` in javascript.

So the equivalent of `'<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>'` would be

```
var errorstring = '<ul><li>' + errorArray.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';
```

Maybe this helps you to change your `$.pnotify` function accordingly.